# How to fix SQLiteException: no such table for 2 tables database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I create 2 tables in difference file (extends SQLiteOpenHelper). Both of them got the same database name.It works well when I got only one table. BUT when I try to use them both. I got this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: wish_table (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM wish_table

This is a part of my 1st table databaseHelper class

```
public class Wishlist_DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

public Wishlist_DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, WishList.DATABASE_NAME, null, WishList.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Wishlist
public static final String TABLE_WISHLIST = "wish_table";
public static final String WISHLIST_ID    = "_id";
public static final String WISHLIST_GOAL  = "goal";
public static final String WISHLIST_TARGET= "target";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String CREATE_WISHLIST_TABLE = "create table "
            + TABLE_WISHLIST        + "("
            + WISHLIST_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + WISHLIST_GOAL         + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + WISHLIST_TARGET       + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    // create  table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_WISHLIST_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + wish_table);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

The 2nd table databaseHelper class is implemented the same way as the 1st one. I only change the table name and column name. so, what should I do?

Comment: Can you be more explicit?Like why do you mean by accessing each one aside works but accessing them both doesn't work. I don't really understand what you did that led you to this.

Comment: Why dont you create second table here itself in onCreate, with another query.

Comment: What line causes the SQLiteException? When does it execute?

Answer (score 0):

it may difference ';' ,i'm not sure but worth to try  `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_WISHLIST + " ( " + WISHLIST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + WISHLIST_GOAL + " TEXT NOT NULL," + WISHLIST_TARGET + " TEXT NOT NULL)");`